# How do I add a stereotype to a UML object in gliffy?

Tags: uml, gliffy

I need to add a stereotype to a UML object in Gliffy.  Any ideas if this can be done?  And how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Gliffly is not a modeling tool, only a drawing tool. No validation is performed. Just add `<<stereotype>>` in the name.

[image: Gliffy's Diagram example with stereotype]